# Cypress: Custom Commands Not Recognised By Webstorm

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am working with Cypress for writing automation tests for a website.

I'm facing a problem in that my custom commands, which I'm adding in the `'cypress/support/commands.js'` file, are not recognised by Webstorm in the test bodies.

However, once I run the actual tests, everything works as needed, so for some reason it's just the webstorm that can't read it correctly.

I've read online and tried the common fix of adding `"supportFile": "cypress/support/index.js"` to the `cypress.json`, but it didn't work for me.

I'd like some input and help. Thanks in advance!

Visualization of the issue

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure that you have this in your `tsconfig.ts`

```js
  "include": ["cypress/**/*.ts"]
```

then your IDE should be able to find the custom cypress commands

Answer (score 0):

@see ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-46440/Recognize-Cypress-custom-commands

Adding an annotation like this worked for me.

For example,

```
/**
 * @memberof cy
 * @method clickNext
 * @param {number} cnt
 * @param {number} wait
 * @returns void
 */
Cypress.Commands.add( 'clickNext', ( cnt = 1, wait = 500 ) => {
    for ( let i = 0; i < cnt; i++ ) {
        cy.get( ctrls.next ).should( `be.visible` ).click()
        cy.wait( wait )
    }
} )
```

Answer (score -1):

A primary method to get your IDE to know about your custom command is to use TypeScript definitions. Refer to the [Cypress docs for details](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Types-for-Custom-Commands).

For IntelliJ platform, there is a `Cypress Support Pro` paid plugin (I'm the author) that simplify managing TypeScript definitions for custom commands. See this overview:[image]

Comment: I'm working with .js files not .ts files. so some of these statements cannot work

Comment: You can continue working solely with js except a single ts file with the definitions. Is that possible in your project?

Comment: Not really, are there no other solutions?

Comment: I'm afraid not.